# Proving the highest product of two numbers with a fixed sum

Tags: products

How to prove that any two numbers with a fixed sum have the highest product when both equal half of the sum?

Example:

Given sum equals $10$.
Why is then $5\times5$ more than $6\times4, 7\times 3, 8\times2$, etc.?

Comment: Note that $(5+x) + (5-x) = 10$.  Now consider $(5+x)(5-x)$ and remember that the square of a number is always non-negative.  Adapt this to the general case.

Comment: As an aside, the observation you are asking to prove is a special case of the [AM-GM Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means).

Comment: As a further aside, this generalises. To maximise the product of $n$ (positive) numbers $x_1, \dots, x_n$ subject to the constraint that $x_1 + \dots + x_n = c$ for some constant $c$, you want to take all of the $x_i$ to be equal to $\frac{c}{n}$

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403077/proving-the-product-of-two-real-numbers-is-maximum-when-the-numbers-are-equal-gi/4221332#4221332

Answer (score 3):

$4xy=(x+y)^2-(x-y)^2$ so since $x+y$ is fixed the product is maximum when $x=y$ so that $x-y=0$

Comment: Mark.In 1 line! Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $$a+b=s$$ then $$ab=a(s-a)=-a^2+sa$$ where $s$ is given.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose  $x+y=k $, where $k $ is a fixed real number. We want to maximise $x\cdot y =x(k-x)=f(x)$. Differentiation w.r.t. $x$ will give us $f'(x)=k-2x$. Equating $k-2x $ to $0$ gives $x=\frac k2 \implies y=\frac k2$.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words.

Given others answerers are providing hints:  Can you see the answer in these (tan) plots of $A = x(n-x)$ for various values of $10 \leq n \leq 20$?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You want two numbers which give a particular sum and you want to maximize their product:

$$m+n = c \tag{1}$$

$$m(n) = ? \tag{2}$$

You can rewrite the first equation in terms of either $m$ or $n$. For instance, if you choose to express it in terms of $n$, you get $n = c-m$. Plugging this in $(2)$, you get

$$m(c-m) = -m^2+cm$$

If you know about quadratics, functions in the form $y = ax^2+bx+c$, you could use the fact that $a$ is negative here, so the quadratic has a *maximum*, which occurs at $h = -\frac{b}{2a}$. Using $a = -1$ and $b = c$, you get $-\frac{c}{2(-1)} = \frac{c}{2}$, so the maximum product occurs when both $m$ and $n$ are half their sum (and are equal to each other).

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left( \;\left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) - t \; \right) \; \; \left( \; \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right) + t \; \right) \; = \; \left( \frac{a+b}{2} \right)^2 \; - \; \;  t^2     $$