# Given 2 integers such that $a+b = 1$ , show that $a*b$ is always less than or equal $\frac{1}{4}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I have 2 integers $a$ and $b$ with $a+b=1$.  How do I show that $a*b \leq 1/4$?

I started by doing the following:

$a=1-b$ so $(1-b)*b \leq 1/4$  and showed that for a $\in$ (-∞ , 0 ] $\cup [1,∞)$ the equation is always negative, but I don't know how to proceed for the interval $(0,1)$.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I made a mistake , I didn't ment rational numebers ... so for example 0.5 * 0.5 is equal with 1/4 mb

Comment: It is true for all real numbers.

Comment: Please consider using MathJax to typeset Mathematics in MSE.

Comment: There are no integers in the interval $(0,1)$; at one point (before editing) the question said rational numbers instead of integers

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:**

$a\times(1-a)=a-a^2=-\left(a^2-a+\frac14\right)+\frac14=\frac14-\left(a-\frac12\right)^2$

Answer (score 0):

$y:= a(1-a)$;

Set $x: = a-1/2$; or $a=1/2+x$;

Then

$y=(1/2+x)(1-(x+1/2))= (1/2+x)(1/2-x)=$

$1/4-x^2\ge 1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

Given two real numbers, $\quad a$ and $b,\quad$ it's easy to show that the geometric mean is less than or equal to the arithmetic mean:

$(a,b) \in \mathbb{R} \implies (a-b)^2 \ge 0 \implies a^2+b^2 \ge 2ab \implies \frac {a^2+b^2} 2 \ge \sqrt{a^2b^2}$.

Now let $A=a^2$ and $B=b^2$ and we have that the $[GM] \le [AM]$:
$$\frac{A+B} 2 \ge \sqrt{AB}\quad \implies \quad AB\le \left(\frac {A+B}2\right)^2\qquad \qquad\Big(\forall (A,B)\in \mathbb R^2\Big)$$
With this you can make the argument that for any $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2$:
$$\begin{align}
a+b&=1\quad \to\\
\frac {a+b} 2 &=\frac 1 2\quad \to\\
\left(\frac {a+b} 2 \right)^2&=\left(\frac 1 2\right)^2\quad \to\\
ab \le \left(\frac {a+b} 2 \right)^2&=\frac 1 4\quad \to\\
ab &\le \frac 1 4\\
\end{align}$$