# Partition of $N$ into integers $a_1,\cdots a_M$ for fixed $M$: how to define an index on [0,1] closest to 1 when the $a_i$ are almost the same?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

Given a fixed integer $N$ that is divided into $M$ (integer sized) pieces, I am looking for an expression which is closer to 1 when the sizes of the $M$ pieces are as equal as possible, and closer to $0$ when the size of the $M$ pieces are as different as possible.

For example, if $N = 12$ and $M = 2$, then $[6, 6]$ should have the largest value (closest to $1$) and $[1, 11]$ should have the smallest value (closest to 0).

As another example, if $N = 12$ and $M = 5$, then $[2, 2, 2, 3, 3]$ should have the largest value and $[1, 1, 1, 1, 8]$ should have the smallest value.

The values that $N$ can take on are $1, ..., 288$.
$M$ can take on values between $1$ and $N$ if $N \le 144$, and is capped at $144$ if $N > 144$.

Comment: How about minimum of your list divided by maximum of your list.  Then $[6,6]$ gives $6/6 = 1$, $[1,11]$ gives $1/11$, $[2,2,2,3,3]$ gives $2/3$, and $[1,1,1,1,8]$ gives $1/8$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before obtaining this indicator on [0,1], a good methodology is to have a way to compare partitions: "this partition is better than this one because...". Assume that we have:

$$N=a_1+a_2+ \cdots + a_M=a'_1+a'_2+ \cdots + a'_M,$$

I will consider the first partition to be "better" than the second one iff

$$\ \Pi_{k=1}^M   a_k > \Pi_{k=1}^M a'_k.$$

Why is the product of constituents a good indicator ?

It is well known that for a fixed sum $N=a_1+a_2$, the maximum product $a_1a_2$ is obtained when $a_1=a_2$ ; one can reverse the process by saying that "the closer $a_1$ and $a_2$, the biggest their product". This can be extended in a straightforward manner to a partition of $N$ into $M$ components $N=a_1+a_2+ \cdots + a_M$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/403077)).

See as well a connected issue in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3222675) to a question of mine. it could be of some help in order to find a normalization giving a full answer to your "quest" for an index belonging to interval $[0,1]$.

**Edit** Afterthought. This "indicator" should work well if $M$ is not too big compared to $N$, say for example $M/N < 1/3$. Otherwise, I would advise to use [**entropy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)), i.e., instead of $a_k$, consider $p_k=\frac{a_k}{N}$ (think to $p_k$ as a probability) and take as measure:

$$E=-\sum_{k=1}^M p_k \ln(p_k)=-\sum_{k=1}^M a_k \ln(a_k)+\ln(N) \tag{1}$$

(additive constant $\ln(N)$ can be ignored).

We can compare (1) with the indicator I advise before the "Edit". Indeed, by taking the logarithm, we maximize :

$$\sum_{k=1}^M \ln(a_k) \tag{2}$$

If all the $a_i$ are about the same "size", maximizing (2) or minimizing (1) are indeed equivalent.

Comment: See my "Afterthought".